# Нагрузка на сервер при запросе типа IN()

Tags: sql, mysql

Такой вопрос: если я делаю sql запрос типа `WHERE id IN(12,3,54,5,6,8,234)` и так далее, не станет ли это причиной, например, падения сервера, если количество этих самых `IN` возрастет до, например, 10000 идентификаторов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну подумайте, 10к идентификаторов. Бегло - это 45к-50к символов. Только распарсить такой запрос - уже проблема. Упасть может и не упадет, но нагрузит капитально.
В любом случае - так лучше не делать.

Answer (score 2):

MS Sql Server бросает исключение, если у запроса более 2100 параметров. У MySql тоже могут быть подобные ограничения. Если мне нужно сделать выборку, у которой в IN больше, чем 2100 значений, я группирую набор значений и делаю несколько запросов.

Comment: хм, кому верить? :) @knes и @KoVadim говорят что все будет ок..

Comment: Зачем верить? Можно сформировать такой запрос и протестировать.

Comment: @Ozim я не говорил, что все будет ок. Скажем так, если запрос будет выполнятся 10 минут, это нормально? может и да, а может и нет.

Comment: Действительно, зачем верить?

    //The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the max_allowed_packet value.

Смотрим в документации по [IN()][1] и по [max_allowed_packet][2]


  [1]:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in
  [2]:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: max_allowed_packet - 1G ? круто. я себе представляю, сколько будет такой "пакет" по сети передаваться. И сколько потом mysql сервер скушает памяти:)

Comment: От сети зависит. По гигабитной - около 10 секунд всего. ^^
А памяти скушает... Стоит полагать, что примерно 1Гб. Запрос-то линейный...

Comment: понял, спасибо всем.

Answer (score 1):

Не упадет. Но при таком количестве уже стоит подумать о введении дополнительного столбца/критерия/кэширующей таблички. 
Часто подобная вашей ситуация возникает в интернет магазинах с большим каталогом, когда требуется перекрестить несколько результатов поиска, а произвести повторный поиск неэкономично. Там применяется кэширование.